# SQL set specific month as first month of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to write a report in SQL which sets the first week of July as the first week of the year.

I have figured out this line below to fetch the week count, but it only works for a year. I.e. if I have a data that is dated July next year, it goes to week 53 (and so on) rather than restarting to week 1.

```
datediff(ww, DATEADD(yyyy,CAST(RIGHT(DATEPART(yy,GETDATE()),2) as INT),'7/1/2000'),
             DATEADD(dd, 8-(DATEPART(dw, S.StartDate)), S.StartDate)) as WeekCount
```

Comment: Are you thinking along the lines of "1 July" is the beginning of the financial year, i.e. it is "day 1" of the year?

Comment: I think you would want to take the modulus of the shifted date.  In other words, the 53rd week would wrap around to 1 again.

Comment: What is the format of `S.StartDate` ?

Comment: What exactly do you want ?? please provide sample date and its output you want

Comment: @Spenzo for example, I have a schedule dated 2nd of July 2015, I'd like this to appear as "Week 1" (the script I have works great on this).  But when I have a schedule dated 2nd of July 2016, it shows it as week 53 rather than week 1. I wonder if this will show "Week 1" if I am currently in year 2016 rather than 2015?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Not necessarily.  But I need the week that has 1st of July in it as the first week. E.g. in July 2015, I'd like 29 June - 5 July date range considered as the first week of the year.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen S.StardDate is something like  2014-03-19 09:49:59.713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
 select 
      (Datepart(week, convert(datetime, 
            substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),@date,6), 1, 7) + '2000'))  % 27) + 1
```

I am really just stripping out the year and always using a year I know works.  Then just (mod) get the remainder of the division by 27.

Comment: It works! Thanks Anthony.  Still trying to understand why there is a (% 27) and a (+ 1) at the end?

Comment: Let me elaborate:  for 1 Jan 2000, 1 Jan is 27 weeks in exactly, so I divide by that (because we are truncating the year an working with essentially the year 2000 dates).  The balance represents the week number, i.e. week 27 is actually week 1.  Understand? :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using this:

```
SELECT  
        FLOOR(
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @date) >= 7 THEN 
            DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date) - (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, @date), 7, 1)) - 1)
        ELSE 
            DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @date) + (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, @date), 7, 1)))
        END
        / 7) + 1
```